# Block MAC address from accessing hosted wifi on laptop

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I use Seventh Gate at work to share the LAN connection over WiFi to my phone. The problem is some of my colleagues have come to know about this and request the WiFi password and I cannot deny them! So now 5-6 users are using this WiFi and choking my bandwidth.
Is it possible using any application to block specific MAC addresses from connecting to my laptop? 
OR
Is there an alternative to Seventh Gate that provides this feature?

I use Avast Internet Security 6 but was unable to find any setting related to this.

Comment: Change the WiFi password ?

Comment: They'll simply ask for the new password once they see that I am using it! Will also invite the ire of some...exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: Hide the SSID... Although those "existing" connections will then say "it still works, look!"... For those that don't know how to manually create a network they won't be able to see the network on their devices.

Comment: Again, this invites the question "Hey how are you using it?"

Comment: I need to be able to tell them "Hey I'm using it, Jack can too and so can Jill...must be some problem with your phone! Sorry!!" :-)

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to change your WiFi password then there is couple alternatives for you:

1. According to SeventhGate documentation (http://seventhgate.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Program%20features) they are developing MAC filtering feature. You can wait until they have completed it and then filter your friends' addresses.
2. You can limit the number of users but it isn't very good option.
3. Documentation also says that they are developing SSID broadcast disabling feature. Changing SSID and disabling broadcast should block unwanted.
4. Change software from SeventhGate to something else or use an wifi access point (which has MAC filtering option) to share connection.

That's all reasonable alternatives I can think of if you want to use SeventhGate

Comment: Like I said, I'm open to suggestions..are there any other applications that already provide this feature?